# executing a program in C linux using fork and exec

Tags: c, linux, fork, system-calls

I want to execute a C program in Linux using `fork` and `exec` system calls.
I have written a program *msg.c* and it's working fine. Then I wrote a program *msg1.c*.

When I do `./a.out msg.c`, it's just printing `msg.c` as output but not executing my program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h> /* for fork */
#include <sys/types.h> /* for pid_t */
#include <sys/wait.h> /* for wait */

int main(int argc,char** argv)
{
/*Spawn a child to run the program.*/
    pid_t pid=fork();
    if (pid==0)
    { /* child process */
    //      static char *argv[]={"echo","Foo is my name.",NULL};
            execv("/bin/echo",argv);
            exit(127); /* only if execv fails */
    }
    else
    { /* pid!=0; parent process */
           waitpid(pid,0,0); /* wait for child to exit */
    }
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: What do you expect /bin/echo to do?

Comment: I don't know. What to write? I was trying to understand it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

/bin/echo msg.c will print msg.c as output if you need to execute your msg binary then you need to change your code to  **execv("path/msg");**

Answer (score 5):

argv[0] contains your program's name and you are Echo'ing it.
Works flawlessly ;-)

Answer (score 2):

your exec executes the program echo which prints out whatever argv's value is;
furthermore you cannot "execute" msg.c if it is a sourcefile, you have to compile (`gcc msg.c -o msg`) it first, and then call something like `exec("msg")`

Comment: Thanks. but could you please explain it in a bit more detail as I am doing it the first time.

Answer (score 2):

C programs are not [executables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable) (unless you use an uncommon C interpreter).

You need to compile them first with a [compiler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiler) like [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/), so compile your `msg.c` source file into a `msg-prog` executable (using `-Wall` to get all warnings and `-g` to get debugging info from the `gcc` compiler) with:

```
gcc -Wall -g msg.c -o msg-prog
```

<sup>Take care to improve the `msg.c` till you get no warnings.</sup>

Then, you might want to replace your `execv` in your source code with something more sensible. Read [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html) and [execl(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/execvp.3.html) and [perror(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/perror.3.html). Consider using

```
execl ("./msg-prog", "msg-prog", "Foo is my name", NULL);
perror ("execl failed");
exit (127);
```

Read [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/).

NB: You might name your executable just `msg` instead of `msg-prog` ....